# Java html/bbcode in post

Tags: java, html, bbcode

i am making some forum based on jsf 2, primefaces 4.0. I wonder how can in java make some input fields for leaving post for members of site. On many php forums ppl use bbcode. I found some parsers like:

[kefir-bb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kefir-bb/)

but they not include all bbcodes from php forums. I also thought on simple html with:

```
 escape=false
```

but there is problem with some encoding, so for exmaple i must use &l t; instead < etc. 
Ofc i could try to deal with one of this ideas, but maybe there is better way? What do you think would be proper to make user friendly with oportunities to well formate fields for making posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the KefirBB and add all bb-codes you want. Please use the latest version 1.0, it supports case ignoring.

http://kefirsf.org/kefirbb/